# How to add an android object into a MySql Database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I try to add an object in my external databse with a JSON. I arrive to get datas from the database, with an inputstream but I can't add a data.

Maybe I have make a mistake in my Android activity or in my PHP code. When I push the addbutton the android activty close and the main activity is displayed and there is no new obect in my database.

I have searched on the web but a lot of tutorial use deprecated ressources.

I execute the "doInBackground" function when pushing a button.

I just want to use java or android native code and don't want to modify my graddle script.

My database contains just a table with the name of town and the primary key.

My java code :

```
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewTown extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddTownActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.10/T1/create_town.php");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                jsonObject.put("name", name);
                String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

                Log.i("doInBackground", jsonString);

                OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonString);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                outputStream.close();
                connection.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("doInBackground", e.getMessage());
            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.i("doInBackground", e.getMessage());
            }

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", jsonObject.toString());

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            try {
                int success = jsonObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                Log.i("onPostExecute", "success :"+String.valueOf(success));

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                }else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }
}
```

My Php code :

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        // on se connecte à notre base  pour recuperer les data
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '',"db_ville"); 
        /* Vérification de la connexion */
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO liste_villes(name) VALUES ('$name')");
        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        $result->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    }
    else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please change the title into a short, clear question.

Comment: 1- change `localhost` in android code to the server's IP address or hostname/domain name, 2- your insert statement looks not complete you are missing the `VALUES ...` part where you have to use the `$name` variable

Comment: just noticed `(null,name)` regarding point 2, if you are directly inserting without listing fields first, you may need to write it as following `...(null,'$name')"`

Comment: I have modified the php code as you say. I work on my local network. My server is not online, but it works. I can ping it or access the web page.

Comment: it's not about local network or online, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` means **this machine**, so when you run android app, localhost will refer to the mobile, as if you have apache, mysql ...etc installed on your mobile which is not the case. so that's why you need to use server's IP address (ex 192.168.1.10) in your **android code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created `jsonObject.put("username", name);`in the android Async task and you have try to get the data on the PHP code by using `$name = $_POST['name']`.
Please change this to `$name = $_POST['username']`.
I think that is the issue please check that,Thanks

Comment: I have made the modifications but I have two android runtime 1 - RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() and 2 - RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). And I used the class httpsURLConnection with a http addresse.

Comment: This error is due to the intent call from doInBackground() method of Async task. Please update the UI only from onPostExecute() method of Async task.